# Iterating Array of Objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an array that consists the objects with a key, value how can we iterate each object for `caste` and `id`.

```
[
    Object {
        caste = "Banda",
        id = 4
    },
    Object {
        caste = "Bestha", 
        id = 6
    }
]
```

Comment: iterate over the array of objects? iterate over object fields? both?

Comment: iterate over array of objects ..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```js
var array = [
   {caste: "Banda", id: 4},
   {caste: "Bestha", id: 6}
];
    
$.each(array, function( key, value ) {
  console.log('caste: ' + value.caste + ' | id: ' +value.id);
}

);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How? I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: for the first iteration it gives me banda and 4 for the second iteration it again gives banda and 4 ,bestha and 6 like that..

Comment: As TheBronx said [see his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16234582/2252829), its just an array. Since that solution uses native Javascript, it might be a better design if you don't want do use jQuery in your project.

Comment: The question was tagged with `jquery`, I though OP wanted a jQuery answer. Or course vanilla JS is faster.

Answer (score 15):

Example code:

```js
var list = [
    { caste:"Banda",id:4},
    { caste:"Bestha",id:6},
];
    
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    console.log(list[i].caste);
}
```

It's just an array, so, iterate over it as always.

Answer (score 10):

In plain JavaScript you can do this:

```
var array = [{caste: "Banda", id: 4}, {caste: "Bestha", id:6}];

array.forEach(function(element, index) {
    console.log(element.id+" "+element.caste);
});
```

The callback function is called with a third parameter, the array being traversed.
For learn [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)!

So, you don't need to load jQuery library.

Greetings.

Answer (score 4):

```
var array = [{caste: "Banda", id: 4}, {caste: "Bestha", id:6}];
var length = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   var obj = array[i];
   var id = obj.id;
   var caste = obj.caste;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Arrow functions are modern these days

Using jquery $.each with arrow function

```
 var array = [
    {caste: "Banda", id: 4},
    {caste: "Bestha", id: 6}
 ];

 $.each(array, ( key, value ) => {
     console.log('caste: ' + value.caste + ' | id: ' +value.id);
 });
```

Using forEach with arrow function

```
  array.forEach((item, index) => {
      console.log('caste: ' + item.caste + ' | id: ' +item.id);
  });
```

Using map with arrow function. Here map returns a new array

```
  array.map((item, index) => {
      console.log('caste: ' + item.caste + ' | id: ' +item.id);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

The forEach loop accepts an iterator function and, optionally, a value to use as "this" when calling that iterator function.

```
 var donuts = [
    { type: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 },
    { type: "Chocolate", cost: 2.45 },
    { type: "Cider", cost: 1.59 },
    { type: "Boston Cream", cost: 5.99 }
];

donuts.forEach(function(theDonut, index) {
    console.log(theDonut.type + " donuts cost $"+ theDonut.cost+ " each");
});
```

Subsequently it can also be broken down to this

```
var donuts = [
  { type: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 },
  { type: "Chocolate", cost: 2.45 },
  { type: "Cider", cost: 1.59 },
  { type: "Boston Cream", cost: 5.99 }
];


function ShowResults(donuts) {  
    console.log(donuts.type + " donuts cost $"+ donuts.cost+ " each");  
}

donuts.forEach(ShowResults);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery to iterate through all the objects jQuery wants you to fill a callback function, which jquery will call back. The first input parameter will be given the key and the second input parameter the value:

```
$.each(dataList, function(index, object) {
   $.each(object,function(attribute, value){
      alert(attribute+': '+value);
   });
});
```

documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: The fourth line should be ```});```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each([your array of objects], function(index, value) {
  // Do what you need, for example...
  alert(index + ': ' + value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over an array filled with stuff in jQuery use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), to iterate over an Object for its properties use for..in